# How to fix a Duet3D board on an Ender 3 frame pausing mid-print

Tags: ultimaker-cura, diy-3d-printer, reprap

I have just installed a Duet3D Wifi 2 on an Ender 3 Pro. I sliced my first print using Cura and uploaded it via the web interface. It prints fine, except that it pauses for 10 seconds several times per layer. This occurs at the same points on each layer. Here is a video I recorded to show the idea: https://vimeo.com/400385336

I have used the Ender 3 profile in Cura 4.4.0, only changing the G-code flavor to RepRap.

I have not been able to identify what is going on, any ideas?

Comment: "changing the G-code flavor to RepRap." - The printer runs on **Marlin** as shipped. Did you flash a different firmware?

Comment: The Duet3D board runs on RepRap https://www.duet3d.com/

Comment: by swapping the board you turned your printer basically into a new machine. Ender3 fixes won't help, you need to use RepRap fixes now. Retagged.